# List of recognized quill toolbar classes

Tags: javascript, html, quill

The documentation for the quill module states:

> ...you can manually create a toolbar in HTML, and pass the DOM element or selector into Quill. The ql-toolbar class will be added to the toolbar container and Quill attach appropriate handlers to  and  elements with a class name in the form ql-${format}. Buttons element may optionally have a custom value attribute.

The example that follows includes examples such as

```
<button class="ql-bold"></button>
<button class="ql-script" value="sub"></button>
<button class="ql-script" value="super"></button>
```

Is there a list of all the recognized ql-${format} classes somewhere that I can reference? It would be really helpful to have a table of these in the [Toolbar documentation section](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A list of [supported formats](https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/).

An [example](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/1.3.7/docs/_includes/standalone/full.html) with the HTML of all the toolbar options.

Comment: Link to example doesn't work anymore